# How can I add lombok to wildfly 19 modules and how I can use it?

Tags: java, wildfly

I have been trying to add the module and it is added, but when I put a "@Getter" or "@Setter" and I try to put "person.getName();" the getters and setter do not appear.

// module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.projectlombok">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="lombok-1.18.22.jar"/>
    </resources>
</module>
```

Comment: Where would you like to put `person.getName();`, where do you expect getters and setters to appear? Please specify your project setup a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Project Lombok is a compile time tool and is not needed at runtime. There is nothing you need to install in WildFly. You need to install/use it in your build process too. See the [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/) for how to install Lombok in your build process.

Comment: I think there are situations where WildFly compiles code on-the-fly (e.g. for JSP pages), so it could be a real problem.

Comment: I don't think you can use lombok with a JSP so I don't know how that would work. Seems like more work trying to get it to work than just adding the getter/setter :)

Comment: I also don't know, but I don't even know if the OP asked for this, so I asked him for more details in the question. Because if he expects that Lombok in a JSP would work, the install in the build process will not help much.

Comment: Hello, in the system I use: wildfly 19, corretto java 11, ejb... etc
It is an architecture with a soap microservice, there are dto and pojo with too many attributes and I would like to use the lombok library, in the end I would just like to see less code.

Comment: It sounds like you don't need Lombok at runtime then. You'll want to see how to incorporate it in your build process.